# Responsive divs with different percent widths and margin

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a responsive template but I have a problem with the widths of my divs and they are all the same size, but they should not be, look at the [code snippet](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGWLvE). I tried some things but they all don't work :/

**Html:**

```
<div class="content">
            <div class="col 4">
                <div class="top">
                    <h4>Top</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="con">
                    <p class="inner">Content</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col 3">
                <div class="top">
                    <h4>Top</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="con">
                    <p class="inner">Content</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col 3">
                <div class="top">
                    <h4>Top</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="con">
                    <p class="inner">Content</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col 3">
                <div class="top">
                    <h4>Top</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="con">
                    <p class="inner">Content</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.content {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.col {
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #bdc3c7;
    margin: 5px;
}

.col .4 {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.col .3 {
    width: 33.33333%;
    float: left;
}

.col .2 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.col .1 {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

.col .top {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #3498db;
}

.col .top h4 {
    padding: 0 10px;
    color: #fff;
}

.col .con {
    width: 100%;
}

.inner {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your class names to something like "col-1", "col-2" ... Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors)

Also, your selectors are wrong. With this:

```
.col .col-1 {}
```

You are trying to access all the element with "col-1" class inside elements with class "col".

You should be doing:

```
.col.col-1 {}
```

To get the elements containing both classes.

Comment: I tried it with .col.4, .. and only .4, .. before but it didn't worked and now it dosen't work as well.

Comment: OK, but that depends on the width you use. You have to play around with values and classes until you get the results you want. If this answer really helped you, please consider marking it as the correct one. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't knew that width: calc(100% - 20px); works in CSS3. Now it's good.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
.col .4 {
   width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.col .3 {
  width: 33.33333%;
  float: left;
}

.col .2 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.col .1 {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
```

Should be this:

```
.col-4 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 33.33333%;
  float: left;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
```

or this, which means all `col` classes that also has another numeric class:

```
.col.col-4 {
   width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.col.col-3 {
  width: 33.33333%;
  float: left;
}

.col.col-2 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.col.col-1 {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
```

Since they're not nested inside the `col` class. As having classes that starts with a number isn't allowed.

Comment: I tried it with .col.4, .. and only .4, .. before but it didn't worked and now it dosen't work as well.

Comment: @DimaKiltau I've updated answer, it works now if you change it like this.

Comment: @DimaKiltau Then you have to adjust the width till you get what you want. Consider accepting this answer.